# heroku-redis keys keep coming back after flushall

Tags: django, heroku, redis

Im trying to delete keys from my heroku-redis python/django app. I do it, looks like its gonne but as soon as a request hists the server API looks like it recreates all the same keys again. I feel like I may be missing to clean the cache somewhere else or need some sort of commit?

here is how im trying

```
heroku run bash --app=myapp
cd myapp
python manage.py shell
import os
import redis
from django.core.cache import cache

r = redis.from_url(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
r.keys()
[LIST_OF_KEYS]
r.flushall()
r.flushdb()
r.keys()
[]

cache.clear()
```

as soon someone call my API if I check r.keys() it has all the keys it used to be again.

Comment: I only know about redis, and haven't used the heroku-redis, Just to be clear, in the redis end there is noway to have keys after flushall

Delete all the keys of all the existing databases, not just the currently selected one. **This command never fails**. - redis.io

Check for application cache, or initialization script

Comment: "soon as a request hists the server API looks like it recreates all the same keys again" so your code is recreating all the keys then. Isn't that what you want